# Как дождаться завершения работы функции callback в js чтобы использовать возвращенное значение дальше

Tags: javascript, callback

Интересует такой вопрос, покажу на примере определения координат пользователя, но вопрос общий. Имеем простой скрипт на получение координат пользователя, который происходит в функции callback

```
var coord;
if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
   coord = position.coords;
   console.log("Первый " + coord.latitude);
});
console.log("Второй " + coord.latitude);
```

Так вот Второй выдаст ошибку, поскольку на тот момент работа функции callback не была завершена.

Как сделать так, чтобы получить значения в переменную и потом использовать их дальше, не опасаясь, что на момент использования данные еще не будут получены из функции обратного вызова?
Неужели все размещать только внутри функции callback как в случае с логом "Первый"?

Answer (score 2):

> Неужели все размещать только внутри функции callback как в случае с логом "Первый"?

Да.

Также можно воспользоваться переписывальщиками кода или альтернативными компилирующимися в жабоскипт языками, которые позволят писать адекватный код с современным await, а не стандартную жабоскриптовую вермишель из колбэков. Если вы пишете на каком-нибудь TypeScript, есть возможность писать "линейный" код, работающий с колбэками, а преобразование человекочитаемого кода в callback hell становится заботой компилятора.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант: [Promise](http://learn.javascript.ru/promise). Но как писал Squidward: легче засунуть все в кэллбэк (на счет TypeScript, CoffeeScript и им подобных сказать ничего не могу т.к. не использую их).